# Is String X a sub sequence of String Y Java

Tags: java, subsequence

Question copied from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5529/is-string-x-a-subsequence-of-string-y

T
Given strings X and Y, determine whether X is a subsequence of Y. The empty string is regarded as a subsequence of every string. (E.g., '' and 'anna' are subsequences of 'banana'.)

**Is their any function already in Java or some common library which does this ?**

Input

X, a possibly-empty case-sensitive alphanumeric string
Y, a possibly-empty case-sensitive alphanumeric string
Output

True or False (or equivalents), correctly indicating whether X is a subsequence of Y.
I/O examples

- ''    'z00'   True
- 'z00'  'z00'  True
- 'z00'  '00z0'   False
- 'aa'   'anna'   True
- 'anna' 'banana' True
- 'Anna' 'banana' False

Comment: Are you saying that you can remove letters from the middle of String Y? For example 'anna' is a subsequence of 'banana' only if you remove an 'a'.

Comment: So only the sequence matters So String a is a subsequence of String b if you can remove a sequence of character from String b  and arrive at String a. So here String.contains will not works as it is like substring and not subsequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use regexes to check that the sequence is contained in your search string (and using a replace to interleave your search characters with the wildcard .*):

```
     String x = "anna";
     String y = "banana";
     x = x.replace("", ".*");  //returns .*a.*n.*n.*a.*

     System.out.println(y.matches(x));  // returns true
```

Comment: +1. This is a better way of doing what I was trying to do. Didn't think to use replace("", ".*")

Comment: This is approach is not working for Strings s1 = "cb" and String s2 = "abc". The code will return true but s1 is not a subsequence  of s2 (order of string is matter while checking subsequence)

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at the String class? `y.contains(x)` should do all or nearly all of what you require.

I just saw you don't need the sequence grouped. No existing function will do what you want but its reasonably easy to write something:

```
boolean stringContains(String container, String contents) {
   // start at the start of both strings
   int rpos = 0;
   int cpos = 0;
   // Scan through till we reach the end of either string
   while (rpos<container.length() && cpos<contents.length) {
       // If they match advance both counts, otherwise just
       // move on through the container
       if (container.charAt(rpos) == contents.charAt(cpos)) {
           rpos++;
           cpos++;
       } else {
           rpos++;
       }
   }

   // If we reached the end of the contents string then we have a match
   return cpos==contents.length;
}
```

Comment: This will work for substring like if x is a substring of y, then y.contains(x) returns true. However x ="banana" y="bann" I require this to be true as y is a subsequence but not a substring of x

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove duplicated characters from both strings, and then you can use `String#contains` to check for subsequences.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex for this:

```
public boolean subsequence(String superString, String subString) {
    StringBuilder sb = (".*");
    for (char c : subString.toCharArray()) {
        sb.append(c);
        sb.append(".*");
    }
    return superString.matches(sb.toString());
}
```

This just inserts `.*` between every character in your matching String, including the beginning and the end.